# Kinect Getting Color Data About A Specific Joint in C++

Tags: kinect

I'm trying to get the color data about a joint (i.e. hip center). However, I do not know how to map the spectral position of the joint to the color frame. I do believe there are similar answers for C#, but it seems like there is almost nothing when it comes to C++.

How can I do it?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  Are you wanting to overlay a skeleton onto the color frame, or extract a bit of information for something?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey What I want to do is to get the color data(RGB) from a region whose center is hipcenter

Comment: In C# there is the "MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint" call.  I realize you are wanting C++ though, so just throwing that out in case you were not yet aware.  I'll look around some, but I've only coded for the Kinect using the C# libraries so far.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey As far as I understood, such a thing is definitely what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ you have to do it in 2 steps,  first get depth data using:

[NuiTransformSkeletonToDepthImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855604.aspx)

This gets you depth coordinates and depth values. Then you can use this to call:

[NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixelAtResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663858.aspx)

to get color space coordinates.