# Kinect convert hand coordinates to image pixels

Tags: c++, kinect

I am working on project with Microsoft kinect. I got coordinates of right hand by APIs provided by Microsoft (Skeleton tracking) and I have a RGB image. Question: Is there any precise way to convert coordinates of hand to corresponding pixel in RGB image ?

Comment: I found that it is possible by scaleTO function in c#. How to do it in c++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`NuiTransformSkeletonToDepthImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/nuiskeleton.nuitransformskeletontodepthimage.aspx) and [`NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663860.aspx) together to find the depth from skeleton space, then find the color coordinates of that point. Also see [Kinect Getting Color Data About A Specific Joint in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972755/kinect-getting-color-data-about-a-specific-joint-in-c)

Comment: @user3333971 Sounds great! You can accept answers so others don't answer